# where is receipt collector sample app described in Google I/O 2014 video?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

In the [Google I/O 2014 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rUZmkifDPk) about the Drive Android API, Jen King describes a "receipt collector" sample app. Is it publicly available? (I didn't see it in the usual places: https://github.com/googledrive, or the SDK samples directory.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not available right now.  The other samples should cover all the same material though.